# JavaScript Promise resolves 'undefined' in Chrome / Edge / etc. but works fine in Firefox

Tags: javascript, promise

So i use the following function:

```
function hideDetails(table) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        if ( countSelected(table) == "multiple" || countSelected(table) == "none") {
            document.getElementById( 'details' ).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById( 'configDetailsWrap' ).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById( 'list' ).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById( 'list_2' ).style.display = 'none';
            resolve();
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById( 'details' ).style.display = 'block';
            resolve();
        }
    })
    return promise;
}
```

which gets called like this:

```
hideDetails(table).then(function() {
                let item = $('#details');
                let position = item.position();
                window.scrollTo(0, position.top);
            },
            function() {
                console.log('Error while displaying details.')
            });
```

This works absolutely fine in firefox, but in all other browsers i have tried (Chrome, Opera, Edge, Safari) i get a console error like the following:

Edge: "Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference"

Chrome: "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

I don't get this. How can the promise be fulfilled in Firefox, but not any other browser?

Comment: If you clear the file cache of all your browsers and try again, does the behavior change?

Comment: what does it resolve to in firefox? because it should resolve to undefined **everywhere** - it seems firefox is the problem with your code

Comment: The promise will resolve to `undefined` everywhere - you're not passing any argument to `resolve()`. The issue with your code seems to be that the `hideDetails(table)` *function call* returns `undefined`.

Comment: Is this the exact code your using? Is this the complete code, and does the error really come from that line - or do you have `then` calls elsewhere as well?

Comment: Why are you using a promise at all here? Everything that `hideDetails` does is synchronous.

Comment: This is the actual code. I have to use a promise, because i need the element to be displayed first, then jump the view to that position. Otherwise i would try to jump to a "not existing" element.

Comment: If i console.log(hideDetails(table)) in Firefox, it logs "Promise state:fulfilled, value: undefined"

Comment: @ToniLatenz you might have an older code cached into FireFox and thus the error is not met there. So I will ask this again: if you clear the cache files of all your browsers, is this behavior changing? I expect this to change on FireFox.

Comment: I cleared the browser cache in Firefox, it still works fine..

Comment: Cleared the cache in Chrome...still does not work

Comment: @ToniLatenz take a look at the Sources tab in FireFox DevTools. Do you see this code there in any of the files?

Comment: @Lajos Arpad i don't exactly know where you mean..in the normal F12-opened dev-tools, there seems to be no "Sources" Tab

Comment: @ToniLatenz sorry, I am used to Chrome. It is the Debugger tab in FireFox. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Open_the_debugger

Comment: @Lajos Arpad yes, all the code is there.

Comment: @ToniLatenz then you might want to put a breakpoint to the code and see if it runs. If it doesn't run, then something prevents it.